# How to add non-aggregated columns in WebDataRocks

Tags: webdatarocks

Some content in the data is detailed information. For functional needs, I need it to be displayed in the report, but it should not be used for aggregation, but displayed in each item. As shown in the picture, the column (name, version) should be displayed in each row, not as a category. What should i do?[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1nZW.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to display raw records instead of aggregated data.

You should try switching to the flat form. Just specify the `grid.type` property of the `options` object as `flat`:

```
{
  options: {
    grid: {
     type: "flat"
    }
  }
}
```

Check out the [official documentation](https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/options-object/) for more information on this point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to flatten some columns, not all columns, like this
| Code | Name | 2021-1-28 | 2021-1-29 |
| A001 | A001  |       20        |       50       |
| A002 | A002  |       30        |       40       |